# BlackBerry: “filesystem not ready” when using USB cable

Tags: blackberry, usb

As part of a BlackBerry project I'm working on I need the ability to store data.  As per RIM's documentation, on handsets running v5 or later OS, we can use the SQLite database versus the more typical PersistenceStore methods.

What I noticed is when my handset (A Torch 2) is plugged-in via the USB cable  - so that I can run code through the debugger - the "SDCard/" and the "store/" are no longer available (both of these are NO longer enumerated when calling `FileSystemRegistry.listRoots`).  Only "system/" is available, but as it's a read-only file system this does me little good.

I need a read/write file system that will be available even if the handset is attached to a PC.

It's worth noting that when I plug my handset in I get a dialog that asks how I want this connected:  Sync Media, Mass storage device, or Charge Only are the 3 options.  It does not matter which I choose ... the effects are the same in that only "system/" is available for a file system.

Any advice or help is greatly appreciated.

--------------------------------------  UPDATE  --------------------------------------

I spoke with RIM's developer tech support on this issue and was simply informed this is a FAD.  Their advice was

> "This is not a bug, it is how the device is meant to function. You can
>   listen for when the device is connected via USB and the data
>   unavailable using SystemListener2."

As such it appears all we can do is alert the user to the fact that by plugging their handsets into the USB cables whatever functionaltiy you might require in your application that would include the file system will temporarily be unavailable.   It might be functions as designed but I hope at some point they'll improve the design.

Comment: That's definitelly a pain for a developer. What if my app is doing smth with SDCard (writing some data from network to a file) on a background thread. Will I get any benefit from the fact I'm notified via a listener that the SDCard has just become unavailable? I don't think so. Of cource, the consequences depend on business logic (sometimes it's just ok to interrupt an action/task), however it looks like we always should expect this to happen and be ready to execute some rollback.

Comment: It's little things like this - poor architecture - that help keep us in business by forcing that "constant progression forward" with newer and better tech ... hopefully RIM's new OS will handle this situation better (Android does a good job on this topic).

Comment: If you're talking about BBX (the OS that comes after BB OS 7), then there is already an official notice from RIM that there will be no Java support for it. So I don't think I'll have a chance to check whether "RIM's new OS will handle this situation better".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid to say I struggled briefly with this and then gave up.

In my experience RIM mounts the SD card on the pc filesystem when you connect it via USB no matter what you do.

If you "eject" your device from the machine you should be able to access the sd card.

Comment: You'd think RIM would have a way to still access the read/write filesystems even when connected via USB.  Afterall, this will cause applications which are running (such as background services) to lose their access to those resources if a user decides to use their Desktop Manager.  I find it funny as there are so many scenarios whereby a user needs to manage large files - which might be part of your app - and once they connect your application will quit working as designed.

Comment: I agree, but considering RIM has a history of crappy developer API's I'm not really surprised.